# Regularity method: size of $\epsilon$-regular graph parts

Tags: graph-theory, regularization

I am applying the Regularity method, as described [for example here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gsarkozy/Cikkek/Grenoble08.pdf).

I do not understand why the size $l$ of the $k$ resulting sets $V_i$, ie:

$l = |V_1| = |V_2| = ... = |V_k|$

has the following size, after the sets has been made super-regular:

$$\frac{n(1 - \epsilon)}{M(\epsilon)} \le l$$

With $M(\epsilon)$ being the upper bound on $k$.

I understand the $n/M(\epsilon)$ part: each set can have at most $n$ elements divided by the $M(\epsilon)$, the maximum number of parts. But where is the $(1 - \epsilon)$ term coming from?

Comment: Did you not notice there is a remainder part $V_0$ of size $\le \epsilon n$?

Comment: Ah ok I see. I thought those were taken care of as you discard the edges inside $V_0$ and connecting $V_0$ to the rest of the graph... but indeed those vertices are still in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $1−ϵ$ term is coming from the $V_0$ part of size at most $ϵn$, thanks Erick!